# Active Directory: What connects the KDC's principals to LDAP entries?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kerberos

In Active Directory, what connects the KDC's principals to their corresponding LDAP entries? For example, my KC principal might be

```
Name[/Instance]@REALM
john/admin@company.com
```

and my LDAP entry might be:

```
dn: cn=john,dc=company,dc=com
objectclass: somewhere
```

but how does Active Directory "connect" the two? SRV records? For example, when I log in (i.e., use Kerberos), how does AD match my Kerberos principal to my LDAP entry?

UPDATE: [This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378170(v=vs.85).aspx) comes close to answering the question, but doesn't clearly explain the flow: "The Key Distribution Center (KDC) is implemented as a domain service. It uses the Active Directory as its account database and the Global Catalog for directing referrals to KDCs in other domains.. The KDC for a domain is located on a domain controller, as is the Active Directory for the domain. Both services [ sic? probably meant the 3 services of Kerberos: AS, TGS, and password reset ] are started automatically by the domain controller's Local Security Authority (LSA) and run as part of the LSA's process."

Comment: If I read your question correctly - it's a bit difficult to understand - you are looking for the attribute called UPN (rather than SPN that mentioned by Jacob's answer below)

Answer (score 2):

An ldap attribute called [SPN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677949(v=vs.85).aspx) (service provider name) the primary being  `HOST`

Comment: Any details here? Your answer doesn't explain why, for example, Administrator has no SPNs: C:\Users\Administrator>setspn -L Administrator
Registered ServicePrincipalNames for CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=company,DC=com:

C:\Users\Administrator>

Comment: users by default have no services, they are users, they are not workstations to have `host` or mssql servers to have `MSSQL` so they do not have SPNs (by default, a mssql service for example would have them added to delegate permissions), the username is your kerberos identity.  type `klist`

Answer (score 0):

If you're more wondering where an AD-joined object is looking to find the realm to authenticate with, yes, it's SRV records.

In the root namespace for the domain, there are `_tcp_ldap`, `_tcp_gc` (for the AD Global Catalog LDAP interface) `_tcp_kerberos` and `_tcp_ktpasswd` SRV records as service locators for anything using the domain DNS for name resolution. There should be one of each for each DC in the domain. The two Kerberos-related ones have UDP SRVs as well

In addition, there are site-specific SRV records. If the domain is segmented into sites by IP subnets, by default, DCs in that IP range will register the same set of SRVs in a `_sitename` subzone. If there are no DCs within a site boundary, all of them will register SRVs in that DNS subzone, although that can be altered by GPO.
Finally, for Active Directory, there is an `_msdcs.[domainFQDN]` zone, which has yet another copy of all the above SRVs. This is what Windows clients use first when identifying services.